# How to get probability vector for all actions in tf-agents?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow-agents

I'm working on Multi-Armed-Bandit problem, using `LinearUCBAgent` and `LinearThompsonSamplingAgent` but they both return a single action for an observation.
What I need is the probability for all the action which I can use for ranking.

Comment: Did you find out out to get the probabilities for these agents? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `emit_policy_info` argument when defining the agent. The specific values (encapsulated in a tuple) will depend on the agent: `predicted_rewards_sampled` for `LinearThompsonSamplingAgent` and `predicted_rewards_optimistic` for `LinearUCBAgent`.

For example:

```
agent = LinearThompsonSamplingAgent(
        time_step_spec=time_step_spec,
        action_spec=action_spec,
        emit_policy_info=("predicted_rewards_sampled")
    )
```

Then, during inference, you'll need to access those fields and normalize them (via softmax):

```
action_step = agent.collect_policy.action(observation_step)
scores = tf.nn.softmax(action_step.info.predicted_rewards_sampled)
```

where `tf` comes from `import tensorflow as tf` and `observation_step` is your observation array encapsulated in a TimeStep (`from tf_agents.trajectories.time_step import TimeStep`)

Note of caution: these are NOT probabilities, they are normalized scores; similar to the normalized outputs of a fully-connected layer.